# Tyring to get all details from tr elements in an HTML table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, beautifulsoup

My code below does a pretty nice job of getting all details from all tr elements in a web page.

```
for link in page_source:
    wd.get(link)
    #print(link)
    html_page = wd.page_source 
    soup = bs(html_page, 'html.parser')

    table_body=soup.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        masterlist.append(cols)
```

The only problem here is that it is blending together some elements that I really want separated.  Here is a great example.  When I run the code above, I get results like this:

```
col5   col7
247    1013
```

Here is sample code that shows how the 2, 4, and 7 are all organized.

```
<g transform="translate(16.5,18.5)"><text fill="black" text-anchor="middle" vertical-align="middle" font-size="8" y="3">2</text><circle stroke-width="2" stroke="green" fill-opacity="0" r="12.5" title="" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2;" data-original-title="success"></circle></g>
<g transform="translate(45.5,18.5)"><text fill="black" text-anchor="middle" vertical-align="middle" font-size="8" y="3"></text><circle stroke-width="1" stroke="gainsboro" fill-opacity="0" r="12.5" title="" style="opacity: 1;" data-original-title="running"></circle></g>
<g transform="translate(74.5,18.5)"><text fill="black" text-anchor="middle" vertical-align="middle" font-size="8" y="3">4</text><circle stroke-width="2" stroke="red" fill-opacity="0" r="12.5" title="" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2;" data-original-title="failed"></circle></g>
<g transform="translate(103.5,18.5)"><text fill="black" text-anchor="middle" vertical-align="middle" font-size="8" y="3">7</text><circle stroke-width="2" stroke="orange" fill-opacity="0" r="12.5" title="" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; stroke-width: 2;" data-original-title="upstream_failed"></circle></g>
<g transform="translate(132.5,18.5)"><text fill="black" text-anchor="middle" vertical-align="middle" font-size="8" y="3"></text><circle stroke-width="1" stroke="gainsboro" fill-opacity="0" r="12.5" title="" style="opacity: 1;" data-original-title="up_for_retry"></circle></g>
<g transform="translate(161.5,18.5)"><text fill="black" text-anchor="middle" vertical-align="middle" font-size="8" y="3"></text><circle stroke-width="1" stroke="gainsboro" fill-opacity="0" r="12.5" title="" style="opacity: 1;" data-original-title="queued"></circle></g>
```

Everything is inside the `<g transform>` tags and they always come right before the `</text>`, if the numbers exist.  Sometimes there are no numbers here.  So, 2, 4, and 7 are all separate and distinct variables, but they are getting merged together.  Also, 10, 1, and 3 are all separate and distinct.  If I can get these numbers comma-separated, or pipe-delimited, I can easily push everything into a data frame to make it organized.

I would like to end up with something like:

```
2|4|7      10|1|3
```

Comment: There's no `<table>` in your HTML.

Comment: I don't see how that HTML is related to the Python code at all.

Comment: The table is referenced as 'tbody'.  It's between <tbody> ... & ... </tbody> tags.

Comment: All the numbers come right before the </text> tags.  In the example above, there is '2','','4','7','','' ... so 2, blank, 4, 7, blank, blank.  Is there any way to parse out those numbers as td elements?  It's almost like you have to go down to another level, or something like that.  I don't totally understand it.

Comment: There's no `<tbody>` anywhere in the HTML you posted. Just `<g>`, `<text>`, and `<circle>`.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how this works, exactly, but I found 'table_body=soup.find('tbody')' online and plugged it into the code I had, and it gave me everything that I wanted, except for the deeper details of the td tags, which are all joined together for some reason.  The name of the actual table in the web site that I'm working with looks like this:
table id="dags" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" role="grid">

Comment: Well, at first I thought this was the right approach.  Now, I'm thinking this may not be the right way to do it.  I have everything I want, but some major things are completely unstructured, and very hard to work with.

Comment: If you post the actual table HTML we might be able to help you. But what you've posted doesn't match the code. You can't just grab code from the Internet and expect it to work, you need to understand it and use it as a guide when writing your own code. Programming is not paint-by-numbers.

Comment: I just added this line:
table_body=soup.find('dags_wrapper')
The name of the table is 'dags_wrapper'.  I just re-ran the code and got exactly the same results.  That's all I know for sure.  Thanks for trying to help guys.

Comment: Why won't you post the actual HTML of the table? Anyway, `soup.find('dags_wrapper')` looks for a `<dags_wrapper>` tag. If it's the ID of the table it should be `soup.find(id='dags_wrapper')`